# Arduino ultrasonic initialisation issue

Tags: initialization, arduino, sensors

Hardware:

- Arduino MEGA 2560
- 2 x MaxBotix MaxSonar-EZ0

Software (relating to Ultrasonics, by no means the entire program):

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    //Ultrasonic Left
    pinMode(26, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(2, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(26, LOW);

    //Ultrasonic Right
    pinMode(27, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(3, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(27, LOW);
}

void readSonar() {
    digitalWrite(26, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(25);
    digitalWrite(26, LOW);
    data[0] = pulseIn(2, HIGH);

    digitalWrite(27, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(25);
    digitalWrite(27, LOW);
    data[1] = pulseIn(3, HIGH);

    return data;
}
```

Problem:

- When the Arduino is first booted, the readings from the two Ultrasonic sensors are not being updated. They are reporting as non-zero values, typically in the range of 500 - 1500. They fluctuate a little (most likely due to noise in the power supply), but tend to stay around the value that they initialise to.
- As per the data sheet for these sensors, there are no obstacles within 14 inches of the sensors during the initialisation stage.
- By simply disconnecting and reconnecting the cable going to the sensors (from the back of the sensor, not directly to the Arduino inputs), I am able to receive accurate readings from the sensors immediately.

Has anyone had this problem before? My setup() function looks 'normal' from the examples that I have seen. In order to fix this problem, I have connected a switch for the active lines of both sensors. This way the Arduino can boot and then I can give the sensors power. This seems like a botched workaround to me, and I would like a hard-coded software solution, if anyone is able to provide one!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the characteristics of the sensor it looks clear that you need to start them with the Rx at 0. Look at this [link](http://www.maxbotix.com/articles/028.htm). This is most probably the reason why you have to disconnect the sensor after you start the Arduino to get it working. You also need to make sure that you have pullup resistors connected to avoid unreliability of the readings.

Comment: Because you are new here, do not forget to mark your preferred answer as accepted when you happy with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, FeliceM. I have pullup resistors and I am also using a low-pass filter on the readings as the timing of the readings isn't critical. That being said, Tau is only 2. Would your suggestion be to remove the LOW pull on the OUTPUT pins in the setup() function? My understanding of the datasheet (now that I've re-read it) is that the RX needs to be left high for the initial calibration. Surely the declaration of the pinMode for OUTPUT and INPUT can stay in the setup() function, also? Or do they need to be called from within the readSonar() function?

Comment: You should have a total of 4 wires (ground and +5 V) + (calibration and analog). In the setup, config the pin for calibration as OUTPUT.In the void loop rise the pin for calibration HIGH, followed by a delay (120) and read the analog pin to get your measurement, then calibration LOW, I would put another delay (50). That should be all. After you load the sketch, disconnect the power from Arduino, then connect it and should work.